# Does the word "Rouch Riders" on an U.S old leaflet in 19th mean "Rough Riders"?

Tags: word-meaning

I was just seeing my country's "the history of the U.S" by a Youtuber before the U.S tight election which comes soon and I encountered a U.S leaflet as the following.

[image]

The above leaflet says, "and the Congress of Rouch Riders Of The World".

Does that "Rouch" mean "Rough" as is explained [**here**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rough+Rider) after I googled by "Rouch Riders"?

The dictionary I pay monthly says the origin of the "rough" is

> Middle English, from Old English rūh; akin to Old High German rūh rough, hairy, Latin runcare to weed, ruga wrinkle, Greek orychein, oryssein to dig, orygē act of digging, Sanskrit rūksa rough, Old Norse rögg tuft, shagginess — more at rug

Would someone help confirm with me?

Answer (score 5):

**Not only does it mean "Rough Riders" it says "Rough riders".**

Compare the fourth letter of "rough" with the G in "Congress". They are clearly identical, and different from the C in "Congress". Lower down you will see that the G of "Rough" is identical with the G of "daring".